# How to create a Microsoft SQL Server database by using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

How to create a Microsoft SQL Server database by using ADO.NET and Visual C# .NET programmatically?

I need to create databases programmatically.

I use this code but after creating database, I cannot add a table to this DB due to permission problem

```
string str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY (NAME = MyDatabase_Data, FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', SIZE = 1MB, MAXSIZE = 5MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);

try 
{
    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally
{
    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
         myConn.Close();
    }
}
```

**my code for Creating Table**

```
string path="";// new DB path

string constring = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + path + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

string qry="create table table1 ( ID int, name varchar(20) )";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);       
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: So, you don't have a permission to create a database..?

Comment: I created Database  but i cannot create Table on same DB

Comment: It just might be the lack of indentation. Fix that first.

Comment: When I create table on this DB   it is showing error Unable to open the physical file . Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

Comment: If it's not the indentation, your SQL Server instance probably doesn't have permissions to write to `C:` ...

Comment: Dude, you msut really learn reading.The error is an OS LEVEL access denied error. NHothing in SQL will fix that ever. Start looking at your file system permissions for the place you create the database file in.

Comment: the problem with, when I create SQL DB in any drive using programmatically only .  It's ok when I create annually . If i give permission to DB (Not to folder) it's working.   But I cannot give permission on each and every DB file manually

Comment: You have shown the code that *successfully* creates a database, but the problem, according to you, is creating a table in the database. So, could you also show the code that creates a table?

Comment: `code`    string path="";// new DB path
string constring = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + path + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
string qry="create table table1 ( ID int, name varchar(20) )";
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();</pre>

Answer (score 1):

According with your code, you created the database, so ... Before you call the command to create the table, Did you anytime add an `"USE DATABASE [DataBaseName]"` in your string variable? In my case, I've had to add this code to create the tables. Of course, you must note for the user's permissions of the connection string commented above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error description, following steps may work. I assume that your SQL server runs on the same machine as your test program.

1. Create a worldwide writable directory (C:\mydbdir).
2. Let the DB file be created there (C:\mydbdir\MyDatabaseData.mdf)
3. Try to create the tables in the DB

As ta.speot.is noted, you are (very likely) missing **write permissions** to C:\ **for SQL server process**.

Comment: In normal case ( when I create DB anywhere in machine manually , it's working    but when i create DB programmatically  , its showing error

Comment: Manual database creation does a bit more stuff than just create a database file and the database record in the master database. Can you connect to the database using interactive admin tools? Please verify that your new db has a valid admin account associated with your windows account.

Comment: Please check the database properties for suspicious elements. BTW, I am missing the database name in your connection string.

Comment: in creating table  i gave correct path which i didn't mention here    .    How to verify DB has a  valid admin account associated with your windows account ? @Thinkeye

Comment: For example: MS SQL Server management studio -> database (name from create database command) -> Security -> Users -> dbo should be tied to your windows login name. Try also to put **Database=MyDatabase** additionally to AttachDbFilename= to your connection string.

Comment: in Server management studio   its working perfectly   but in visual studio 2010 its not working and from program also

Comment: I am very sorry, but I can't suggest anything sensible without seeing the details myself. However, if you are able to compare working vs non working database example with Server management studio, you might be able to figure out yourself. Compare everything, starting with file system permissions, over all database settings, ending with last connection string. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You created a database but you did not set the permissions to it.
So after database creation add:

```
var userName = "sa"; // username that is used in the connection
var str = String.Format("USE MyDatabase; EXEC sp_changedbowner '{0}'", userName);
```

Do a ExecuteNonQuery with this as well and then you have the rights to add tables, etc.

**EDIT**

Btw: Sidenote: I would just execute

```
USE master; IF ( NOT(SELECT IsNull(db_id('myDBname'),-1)>0) ) CREATE DATABASE 'myDBname'
```

and let the SQL server do the rest. Easier to create like this, but it is just another way how to do it.